# "refresh fields" not working for MDX query in SSRS 2008 dataset

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx

I've tested the query in MDX Studio 0.4.10 (works fine) and updated the query used in the dataset, however, the resultset has not updated with the new column/field showing in the 'report data' pane, not even when the 'Refresh Fields' button is pressed.

I've even closed and reopened the report but still no new column is showing in the 'report data' pane.

How can I force a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to stick the MDX in the Query Designer and hit the red **!** and it should refresh the fields. Then you can stick the MDX back into an expression and it will remember the fields it found.